# Same query when written in MySQL and python is generating different results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pizza sales dataset, snapshot of the same is below. The query is to find total orders placed on every day of the week.

[Link to the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WZDqj4fCgPg4__TG37U6WKWjJoXOpv3K/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

While using Python, I created a new column called 'week_day'. Then gave the following query:

```
data.groupby('week_day')['order_id'].nunique()
```

Result:

```
week_day
Friday       3359
Monday       2940
Saturday     3126
Sunday       2710
Thursday     3173
Tuesday      2978
Wednesday    3064
```

In MySQL, I used the below query:

```
SELECT 
    DAYNAME(order_date) AS order_day, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS total_orders
FROM pizza_sales
GROUP BY DAYNAME(order_date);
```

Result:

```
order_day    total_orders
Friday       3538
Monday       2794
Saturday     3158
Sunday       2624
Thursday     3239
Tuesday      2973
Wednesday    3024
```

In Power BI, on performing the same task, I am getting answers similar to MYSQL.

What I am doing wrong in the Python code to get different results?

Comment: Are there any NULL OrderIDs perhaps? Aggregate functions eliminate NULLs. Or the data just isn't the same.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in a `week_day`. If you correct extract a day name from `order_date` you should get the correct output:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("pizza_sales.csv")
data['week_day'] = pd.to_datetime(data['order_date'], format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.day_name()
data.groupby('week_day')['order_id'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
week_day
Friday       3538
Monday       2794
Saturday     3158
Sunday       2624
Thursday     3239
Tuesday      2973
Wednesday    3024
```